# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

I was trying to upgrade my Spring and Hibernate version. I was using hibernate 3 and now I have upgraded to hibernate 4.3.6. After upgrading I am getting a weird issue in ehcache implementation.

As I have upgraded to hibernate 4, i have added one entry as:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory </prop>
```

And now I am getting the exception as:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:603)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2440)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSettings(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    ... 147 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:87)
    ... 150 more
```

The libraries used are:

```
antlr.jar
aopalliance.jar
asm-3.3.jar
aspectj-1.7.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.5.4.jar
backport-util-concurrent-1.1_01.jar
c3p0.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.5.0.jar
gson-2.3.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
jakarta-oro.jar
jboss-logging-3.2.0.Final.jar
jdom.jar
jsr107cache-1.0.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
ojdbc14.jar
poi-3.6-20091214.jar
samlutility.jar
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
xmlsec-1.4.5.jar
```

I tried all the possible ways but this is not fixing this issue.

Comment: Are you configuring Hibernate using spring? If so make sure the versions are compatible ie., spring vs Hibernate versions

Answer (score 8):

In Hibernate 4, if you want to use Ehcache, you must add a specific dependency: hibernate-ehcache

But it embeds Ehcache 2.4.3 So you should exclude the embeded Ehcache dependency.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
 <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
         <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For Hibernate-ehcache from version 5.1.0.Final which uses Ehcache 2.10.1 the same exclusion looks slightly different (`ehcache` instead of `ehcache-core`)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
 <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
         <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
         <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and then depending on the version of ehcache, you need to add ehcache or ehcache-core

Up to 2.6.x:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
 <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

for 2.7 and above

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
 <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.0</version> <!--  or above --> 
</dependency>
```

and for 3.0 and above

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Using Ehcache 3.0 and above with currently available Hibernate-ehcache version (5.2.10.Final) is probably not possible (there will be errors). You can use only Ehcache 2.x.x with it. But it is for now. In future it will probably change with new Hibernate-ehcache version.

Answer (score 5):

**use following dependency:**

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```